# xen to KVM local, no active hypervisor

Tags: centos, kvm, libvirt

I had a `xen` server (`centos 5 base`) that was running a set of Linux VM's. Said server has perished in a ball of fire. While it might be possible to save it at some point, in the meantime I really need to get those VM's back online...Problem is, my other VM host is KVM based. I have backups of all the xen config/xml files, as well as the `.img` file, moved over to the KVM system...

But I'm not sure how to convert the xen VM to a KVM, as all the `virt-v2v` guides reference pulling over ssh from an active hypervisor.

I'm also not sure what to do about the xen kernel currently running on the system...Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my solution.

First I needed to mount the drive image based on the offset, bind mount /dev, chroot to the mount and download a non-xen kernel:

- To get the partition info of the drive

  ```
  fdisk -l /images/server1.img
  ```
- Mount the drive, the offset is the Unit size listed in fdisk Multiplied by the start point listed in fdisk

  ```
  mount -t auto -o loop,offset=<offset goes here> /images/server1.img /mnt/server1
  ```
- Mount the boot partition. Same rules apply

  ```
  mount -t auto -o loop,offset=<offset goes here> /images/server1.img /mnt/server1/boot
  ```
- Bind mount /dev (/dev/urandom is required by yum to download things)

  ```
  mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/server1/dev
  ```
- chroot to the drive

  ```
  chroot /mnt/server1
  ```
- install kernel, and exit chroot

  ```
  yum -y install kernel
  exit
  ```
- umount everything

  ```
  umount /mnt/server1/dev
  umount /mnt/server1/boot
  umount /mnt/server1
  ```
- Install virt-v2v, and use it to convert, targeting the "disk" type

  ```
  yum -y install virt-v2v
  virt-v2v -i disk /images/server1.img -o local -os /images/
  ```
- start new vm

  ```
  virsh create /images/server1.xml
  ```